In Vue.JS, How to pass and change props value into nested components?
My requirement is very basic and easy, but not sure why even ChatGPT keeps giving me answer that has warning messages.
I am using Vue 2.
I have three nested components: GrandParentComponent, ParentComponent, ChildComponent.
Now I have a data someId in GrandParentComponent and I want to pass this data all the way down to the ChildComponent and change it.
GrandComponent.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    {{ someId }}
    <ParentComponent :someId.sync="someId"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ParentComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      someId: [] // Initial value
    };
  }
};
</script>

ParentComponent.vue::
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildComponent :someId.sync="someId"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  props: {
    someId: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

ChildComponent.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="selectIds">Select IDs</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    someId: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectIds() {
      // Simulate generating new ids
      const randomIds = [1, 2, 3];

      // Emit the update event with the new ids
      this.$emit('update:someId', randomId);
    }
  }
};
</script>

The above code is generated by ChatGPT and it can work, however, it keeps showing following message in the browser console:

Is there any reason why it shows this warning message? How can I fix this warning issue?
Is it the correct way to pass the props value and change the value in Vue?

You should handle the emit in parent component then emit it again to grandparent component, but this pattern of drilling down the props is bad, you can use provide/inject instead

Could you give an example of using it?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject

It tried it. Now the warning message becomes: "Avoid mutating an injected value directly since the changes will be overwritten whenever the provided component re-renders. injection being mutated: "someId"". Is it actually the right way to mutate value passed from nested components?

Provide also the method from grandparent that mutate the data

Yah, I tried that as well. It still the same warning message...
Is using the Vuex store the only solution? However, in my case, I only have this value need to pass through components, I don't want to create a vuex store just for this value. Is there any other better solution?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@BoussadjraBrahim "this pattern of drilling down the props is bad" - not really. It's ok for a shallow hierarchy. provide/inject isn't much better than mutating prop object in terms of maintenance

The original code is not workable because it doesn't contain a part that modifies someId; update:someId doesn't do this without a listener.
ParentComponent should pass through a value in both ways in order to implement two-way data binding. The following changes are needed:
GrandComponent.vue
<ParentComponent :someId="someId" @update:someId="someId = $event" />

ParentComponent.vue
<ChildComponent :someId="someId" @update:someId="$emit('update:someId', $event)" />

ChildComponent.vue
<button @click="selectIds">Select IDs</button>

If the components use someId as main value, someId prop and update:someId event can be renamed to value and input accordingly in order to follow v-model convention in Vue 2, this allows to use v-model="someId" in GrandParentComponent. Vue 3 allows to use other prop names besides value like v-model:someId="someId", the use of update:someId event name suggests the code was originally intended for this use.
